# Add text in front of grouped values in pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create an Excel Pivottable that grabs data from an Access Query and then shows the values grouped by what I want. That part works fine enough, what I would like to know is if it is possible to add text infront of grouped values in a way that is smart? The purpose is to just be able to change which Access database it should grab data from and have a standardised view where no manual changes have to be made.

What I currently have:

[image]

What I would to have:

[image]

As far as I can see I can add it manually, but there might be new cases of Øxxx types.

Answer (score 0):

I would add reference table with columns sufficient to join to your view and then "prefix text" column that would be appended in front of the existing (quantity in english?) column. Or you could add it to the pivot. This method let's you add/delete rows from the reference table as needed.

If you cannot alter the access side for some reason, then another way is select all the raw data to a sheet and then use VLOOKUP or some other formula to add the prefix. And then pivot this data sheet.